# use same istance of pm2 for ALL USERS

Tags: pm2

I have pm2 installed by default from the root user in /root/.pm2 (~/.pm2)
After that, i had some users with their homes.

But when i enter with one of that user, and i use `pm2 list` or `pm2 start`, and it uses the .pm2 installed in the users dir and so it recreate the same e new pm2 instance. SO how can i make that all other users, uses the same default .pm2 istance/folder? (they already have the permissions to access that folder).
I need that all users can manage the same processes

Thank you!